# Android - Call default browser with and redirect to a designated url

Tags: android

Hi
I want to write an app to call default browser and redirect to a designated url.
Any suggestion to 1)call the default browser, 2)redirect to a designated url.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you just want to launch an ACTION_VIEW intent with the Uri of the webpage as your data element :

```
Intent httpIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
httpIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.bbc.co.uk"));

startActivity(httpIntent);
```

Comment: After compiled the program, it works. However, when I go back to Android desktop and click the app again, it can't go to the browser. What happened?

Answer (score 2):

To open the default browser use an Intent with the action VIEW. To tell the browser which page to load us the data-part of the Intent.

Example:

```
Intent browse = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com"));
startActivity(browse);
```

Since this is a basic task in Android you might want to read some basics about [Intents](http://d.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) in Android.