# iPhone4 - Call default browser with and redirect to a designated url

Tags: iphone

Like this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149525/android-call-default-browser-with-and-redirect-to-a-designated-url), I would like to write an app for iPhone4 to call default browser with and redirect to a designated url, could someone please suggest the code for this action?

Comment: By default browser, do you mean Safari? Or do you mean an embedded web-view? (see the UIWebView class)

Comment: Yes, it should be Safari

Comment: Use as i described in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-[UIApplication openURL:]` method, which is accessed through the `sharedApplication` method of `UIApplication`.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Comment: I got "HelloWorldViewController.h", "HelloWorldViewController.m" and "HelloWorldViewController.xlb", which file should I put the code in?

Comment: @Charles Yeung : the code in my answer is very simple and standard to invoke browser in iPhone APps. Any way , you should put "HelloWorldViewController.h", "HelloWorldViewController.m"  in  your application **class** directory and "HelloWorldViewController.xlb" in your **Resoures** directory of your apps in "XCODE" .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to ask the code of "[[UIApplication shared...gle.com"]];" is belong to which file? Not the file is belong to which folder, thanks

Comment: @Charles Yeung : Put it in any **.m** class of your application.